# Henry Block and self Cat Balou in Bang

Tags: bang

When playing Henry Block, if you Cat Balou or Panic the rattlesnake from yourself for example, are you the target of a bang! ?

Edit:

**Henry Block**

> Any player drawing or discarding one of your cards (in hand or in play) is the target of a BANG!

**Cat Balou**

> Discards a random card from the hand of any player or any card in play

**Panic**

> Pick a random card from the hand of a player or any card in play (at range 1)

Sorry if the wording is not correct, I'm trying to translate from the french version

Comment: This one is tricky. By the literal reading of the cards, it seems like it would be yes, but it seems unlikely that that was the intent.

Comment: I agree, but if the wording says so, I'll play that way :)

Comment: Can you please include what each of those cards does? Makes it a lot easier for people to help answer if they are not familiar with all the cards in question.

Comment: I am not familiar with rattlesnake but I am guessing that is a card played in front of you?

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen an offical answer or FAQ on this topic but I do know that there is another answer on this site that references playing a bang against yourself which says that is not possible. That answer references a post elsewhere which it says is from the developer that says the rule is in place to prevent unfair behavior.

[Post](http://www.bang.cz/forum/viewtopic.php?f=24&t=488#wrap)

> As I said, the "no-killing-yourself" rule is the official one to prevent unfairy behaviours in tournaments.
>
> However, if you sure to play with fair people, you can allow self-shot, which adds strategic elements to the game as well (think of Bart Cassidy, for example).

[Answer](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/3246) where the information came from

What I get from that is if you play a Panic or Cat Balou on yourself as Henry Block you will not have a bang shot at you.